# List param into sheet_name pandas read_execel()

Tags: python, pandas

Im trying to send a list in sheet_name for access more then one sheet from .csv file and when i print df "`df = pd.read_excel( "https://www.football-data.co.uk/mmz4281/2122/all-euro-data-2021-2022.xlsx?raw=true", sheet_name=liga)`" works, he print me two sheets but in next line he said "unhashable type: 'list'"

This is the code:

```py
def liga(liga):
    print(liga)
    df = pd.read_excel(
        "https://www.football-data.co.uk/mmz4281/2122/all-euro-data-2021-2022.xlsx?raw=true", sheet_name=liga)
    print(df)
    df = df[['Date','HomeTeam','AwayTeam','HTHG','HTAG','HTR','FTHG','FTAG','FTR','B365H','B365D','B365A','B365>2.5']]
    df.columns = ['Date', 'Home', 'Away', 'Goals_H_HT', 'Goals_A_HT', 'Result_HT',
                  'Goals_H_FT', 'Goals_A_FT', 'Result_FT', 'Odds_H', 'Odds_D', 'Odds_A', 'Odds_Over25_FT']
    print(df)

liga(["D1","D2"])
```

```
Error:
`Traceback (most recent call last):
File "c:\Users\Ricar\Desktop\Pyhon\teste.py", line 20, in<module>liga(["D1","D2"])
File "c:\Users\Ricar\Desktop\Pyhon\teste.py", line 16, in liga 
df=df[['Date','HomeTeam','AwayTeam','HTHG','HTAG','HTR','FTHG','FTAG','FTR','B365H','B365D','B365A','B365>2.5']]
TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'`
```

Comment: try to convert list in string using str(liga) ?

Comment: but i need a list to acess more then one sheet of my csv file

Comment: Please include stacktrace

Answer (score 0):

`pd.read_excel` returns a dictionary like

```py
{'D1': dataframe1, 'D2': dataframe2}
```

You need get the dataframe with dictionary key like

```
    d = pd.read_excel(
        "https://www.football-data.co.uk/mmz4281/2122/all-euro-data-2021-2022.xlsx?raw=true", sheet_name=liga)
    df = d['D1'][['Date','HomeTeam','AwayTeam','HTHG','HTAG','HTR','FTHG','FTAG','FTR','B365H','B365D','B365A','B365>2.5']]
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer...So and D2 how do i do?

Comment: @RicardoMagalhaes Don't understand, but it totally depends on you.

Comment: To put 'D2' I need to create another dataframe?

Comment: @RicardoMagalhaes What do you mean by `put D2`?

Comment: df = d['D1'][['Date','HomeTeam','AwayTeam','HTHG','HTAG','HTR','FTHG','FTAG','FTR','B365H','B365D','B365A','B365>2.5']], to put d['D2'] i need to create another dataframe?

Comment: @RicardoMagalhaes you can also do `d['D1'] = d['D1'][['Date','HomeTeam']]`